# How manipulate every string that a IList gives you?

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, selenium

I have a list that is given by this page http://www.codigo-postal.pt/?cp4=4710&cp3= , and as you can see if you visited the link there's a line that always end with the word "Braga", so with no further ado, what I want is to manipulate every string that the list gives me, into last word after the comma?

The List is given by this code:

```
IList<string> Distritos = new List<string>();
foreach (var Distritoelemen in Gdriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("local")))
{
    //Distritos.Add(Distritoelement.Text);
    table.Rows.Add(Distritoelement.Text);       
}
```

Comment: I can't tell if you want the word after the last comma, or everything before the last comma

Comment: The word after the last comma, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the word after the last comma, run this code...

```
IList<string> Distritos = new List<string>();
foreach (var Distritoelemen in Gdriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("local")))
{
    //Distritos.Add(Distritoelement.Text);
    table.Rows.Add(Distritoelement.Text.Substring(Distritoelement.Text.LastIndexOf(',') + 1));
```

You might want to consider putting the Text into a local variable. If you don't want the extra space before the word, you can use `.Trim()` on the result of Substring as in `...LastIndexOf(',') + 1).Trim());`

Comment: Is there a way to add the distritoelement.text to the rows of a respective column? By the way, thanks for answering my question

Comment: Yep, I don't know what type of table you are working with, but you should be able to specify where it goes. If it's a database, you can insert directly into it and specify the column you want. Depending on what type of table you have, you should be able to use a `Row` constructor or factory method to add a row that conforms to what you want.

Answer (score 0):

And if you have more then one list you should do

```
 IList<string> Freguseia = new List<string>();
        foreach (var freguesiaelement in Fdriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("local")))
        {
            Freguseia.Add(freguesiaelement.Text);
        }
        IList<string> GPS = new List<string>();
        foreach (var gpselement in Fdriver.FindElements(By.ClassName("gps")))
        {
            GPS.Add(gpselement.Text);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Freguseia.Count; i++)
        {
            table.Rows.Add( Freguseia.ElementAt(i), GPS.ElementAt(i));
        }
```